# Comparing asymptotic forms of series

Tags: asymptotics

I've run into some asymptotic analysis in research here and there and largely it feels pretty magical to me. My research has led me to consider the following question which I haven't the slightest idea how to address:

> If we have two series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ with $a_n,b_n\in\Bbb R$ which converge everywhere and $a_n \sim \frac{b_n}{n}$, can we conclude anything about the asymptotic behavior of $f$ in relation to $g$?

For example: if, say, $g(x) \sim x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ at infinity, could we conclude that $f$ decays at least as fast as $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ at infinity? It seems reasonable to me to think that this would be the case but asymptotic analysis is pretty counter-intuitive at times, especially when the coefficients are allowed to oscillate.

Comment: Can you restrict your problem to $b_n\geq0$? Otherwise I would search for a counterexample with oscillating  $b_n$ and $a_n = |b_n|/n$.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $\sim$ here? If $a_n \sim b_n$, do you mean that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1 + o(n)$? Similarly, what precisely do you mean by $g(x) \sim x^{-1/2}$ at infinity?

Comment: @mixedmath Here, I mean that $a_n = \frac{b_n}{n+\varepsilon}$ where $\varepsilon > 0$ is small so in this context $\sim$ means approximately equal, I suppose. The statement at infinity is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}=C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: @AD. They both have the same sign so no issues like that. I did think of that issue, though.

Comment: Do you really mean "there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $a_n=b_n/(n+\epsilon)$ for every $n$", or is it another approximate  thing? Because if this relation is true, then $g$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $f$ and $f'$. In any event, clarifications should be edited into the question, not left in comments.